# How can I create a 2D array with 1 to n in one column and zeros in the other - Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I tried creating two arrays and then adding them together

```
array_nmax = np.arange (100)
array_zeros = np.zeros (100, dtype = np.int)
array_final = np.append (array_nmax,np.zeros, axis = 0)
```

but it says that they're not the same dimensions even though they should be both 100 by 1 arrays.

Comment: Use `np.column_stack`.

Comment: or its visual cousin... out = np.c_[array_nmax, array_zeros]

Comment: Your error is because you made a typo - why are you passing `np.zeros` instead of `array_zeros`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
a = np.zeros((100, 10), dtype=np.int)
a[:, 0] = np.arange(0, 100)
```

Comment: zeros(100, 2) I think

Comment: sure, if it has two columns it should be 2.

Comment: that is what the title implies... two columns

Answer (score 0):

Slower than @GrigorisG's answer and not so readable, but still a possible solution:

```
np.arange(100)[:,None] * [1,0]
```

By the way, there are two problems in your solution. The first one is that, by mistake, the second argument to `concatenate` is the function `np.zeros` instead of the newly created array `array_zeros`. Even after fixing this, the second problem is that the two arrays will be concatenated along their zero-th dimension and the result will be an array of shape `(200,)`. You should use `np.column_stack` as suggested by @Divakar.